# merge values in select

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, case

I have next part of query:

```
SELECT types, count
FROM ...
```

Result is next:

```
types        count
soft         3
lite soft    2
middle soft  7
hard soft    2
other        5
```

what I need is to merge results soft, lite soft and other as other.
to get next table:

```
types        count
middle soft  7
hard soft    2
other        9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression`:

```
select (case when type in ('middle soft', 'hard soft') then type else 'other' end) as type,
       sum(count)
from t
group by type;
```

If you want the result in a particular order -- say with `other` at the end, then a lateral join helps:

```
select v.type, sum(count)
from t cross join lateral
     (values (case when type in ('middle soft', 'hard soft') then type else 'other' end)
     ) v(type)
group by v.type
order by (v.type = 'other') asc,  -- put it last
         count(*) desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider a `case` expression to transcode the `types`, then aggregation:

```
select 
    case when types in ('middle soft', 'hard soft') then types else 'other' end as new_types, 
    sum(count) cnt
from mytable
group by 1
```